# SQL - How can I exclude one row that is identical to another from a query result?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am writing a SQL query that deals with orders for products (lens for glasses).

In the database, one order can have multiple rows. Each row represents a different item within the order. So one row will be the right lens, and we will have another row for a `right.optionA`, `right.optionB` etc. Same for left Lens.

In my query, one row is one lens, along with all the options that go with it.

My problem is that there are a couple of orders that have errors. The error is that one of the options has been entered twice, but it is not possible to have two options of that type.

My query has been written to only consider one of these specific options per lens (so per row), therefore it generates an additional row when this error happens (along with additional quantities, sales, etc).

I do not want to change my query to take into consideration multiple options of that type, because it is not suppose to happen, so I can not do a `SUM` of the data that goes with those rows and a `GROUP BY`.

So my question is, how to say in SQL that I just want to consider the first row?

Right now my idea would involve a count(*) on the rows of that option type and when it is bigger than 1 it should do something, but I don't know what.

Here is a screenshot of what an order with an error looks like. The `CompType` column represents the type of the item. The `CompType` `03` is where the error is. We can see the rows are there twice, which is the problem:

[image: Example of Error Rows]

I tried to keep it as short as I could, I know it's a bit of long read, sorry about that.

Thanks and have a nice day.

Comment: The rows aren't identical because of the `position` column.  Easiest fix is to `MIN(position)` or `MAX(position)` then `GROUP BY` the other columns.

Comment: @AaronDietz I'd add this as an answer...

Comment: @aaron Dietz Thanks a lot! I'll read up on the MIN and MAX and give it a shot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rows aren't identical because of the `position` column. Easiest fix is to `MIN(position)` or `MAX(position)` then `GROUP BY` the other columns.

Example with `MIN()`:

```
SELECT OrdNumb,
       Side,
       MIN(Position),
       Comptype,
       --Rest of cols
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY OrdNumb,
         Side,
         Comptype,
         --Rest of cols
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on which "position" is the correct one.  It must return multiple rows since there are multiple values, but as you said they are errors.  What I would do is assume that if there are multiple "positions" per "comptype" (which is what seems to be the issue) then in order to get rid of one of the values just choose either the min or max of the positions column and only group by the other categories.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I think the most important thing to stress here is to clean the data in the system.  But that being said, assuming you always want the first of the duplicates by position and that the troubled rows are always exact duplicates of the good row - this should do the trick :

```
SELECT OrdNumb, Side, MIN(Position) AS Position, Comptype, RecType, Compcode, FrameNo, ItemCode, CompDescr, Quantity
FROM OrderLine
GROUP BY OrdNumb, Side, Comptype, RecType, Compcode, FrameNo, ItemCode, CompDescr, Quantity
```

Comment: Thanks. Yeah I know that would be ideal but I do not own this database. Thanks for the idea, will try is asap.